# Create Frontend and backend for Pgadmin Database

Tags: sql, pgadmin

I created database fir online music service using pgadmin.(I used dummy datas for create it because its for my uni project) So, It include 7 tables. Can anyone guide me method for create simple ui for it. Using JS, Ruby or qt(c++) or maybe python(But I'm not much familiar with python) I tried by googling. But couldn't get any clear method. If you gave any resources It'll be great. Thanks for your reply.